# How to let newB access getX function?

Tags: javascript

I think that I set everything correctly by using the call function to pass variable x from parent b, but still receive the error which is "newB.getX is not a function". I am a beginner please give me some hints and explanation, thank you.

```
 const a = function(x) {
  this.x = x
}

a.prototype = {
  getX() {
    return this.x;
  }
}

const b = function(x, y) {
  a.call(this, x);
  this.y = y;
}

b.prototype = {
  getY() {
    return this.y;
  }
}

const newB = new b('x', 'y');
console.log('question 5:', newB.getX());
console.log('question 5:',newB.getY());
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing `a.call(this, x);` only runs `a`'s constructor, which only assigns a property to the instance. It doesn't change any of the internal prototypes. `newB`'s prototype chain remains:

instance (has property `x`) <- b.prototype (has getY property) <-Object.prototype

`a.prototype` is not in the chain, so `getX` is not visible on the instance.

I suppose you could iterate over all of `a`'s prototype properties and assign them to the instance.

```js
const a = function(x) {
  this.x = x
}

a.prototype = {
  getX() {
    return this.x;
  }
}

const b = function(x, y) {
  a.call(this, x);
  for (const [key, prop] of Object.entries(a.prototype)) {
    this[key] = prop;
  }
  this.y = y;
}

b.prototype = {
  getY() {
    return this.y;
  }
}

const newB = new b('x', 'y');
console.log('question 5:', newB.getX());
console.log('question 5:',newB.getY());
```

Or do it in `a`'s constructor

```js
const a = function(x) {
  this.x = x;
  this.getX = () => this.x;
}

const b = function(x, y) {
  a.call(this, x);
  this.y = y;
}

b.prototype = {
  getY() {
    return this.y;
  }
}

const newB = new b('x', 'y');
console.log('question 5:', newB.getX());
console.log('question 5:',newB.getY());
```

Or use a `class`, which is probably the preferred modern method of subclassing (over manually extending functions)

```js
class a {
  getX = () => this.x;
  constructor(x) {
    this.x = x;
  }
}
class b extends a {
  getY = () => this.y;
  constructor(x, y) {
    super(x);
    this.y = y;
  }
}

const newB = new b('x', 'y');
console.log('question 5:', newB.getX());
console.log('question 5:',newB.getY());
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your explanation is so clear!